# Как правильно включить Strict Mode в Android Cordova

Tags: java, android, cordova

Я модифицирую через `hook` `CordovaActivity.java`. Я вставляю `striсt mode` в `onCreate` а в `onTouchEvent` вставляю бесконечный цикл:

```
package org.apache.cordova;

. . . 
import android.os.StrictMode;

public class CordovaActivity extends Activity {
    . . .

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        . . . 
       
       StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .detectAll()
                .penaltyLog()
                .build());
        StrictMode.VmPolicy policy = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                .detectAll()
                .penaltyLog()
                .build();
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(policy);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        . . .       
    }

    
   @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        long a = 0;
        while(true) {
            a++;
            if(a == 8000000000L){
                return true;
            }
        }  
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
         int action = ev.getAction();
         Log.d("dispatchTouchEvent WWW", "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW");

         super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
         long a = 0;
         while(true) {
              a++;
              if(a == 8000000000L){
                  return true;
              }
        }  
    }
    . . .
```

В приложении не вижу красной рамки, на других приложениях вижу. То есть `Strict Mode` у меня на телефоне включен. Либо я его включил неправильно в приложении либо бесконечный цикл не там сделал. Как правильно включить это все чтоб его увидеть.